# Where can I find the complete list of attributes for a control?

Tags: asp.net

Where can I find the complete list of attributes for a control? If I wanted to use textbox control on my asp.net application, where can I find the complete list of attributes associated with it? I know some of the them can be found in the properties area in the IDE. But the properties area did not have the "OnTextChanged" attribute listed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. You are encouraged to ask questions. But as a beginner for these doubts you can get informations by searching the resources in net. Pleas try to get answer by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a web control, if you have the properties window open, then you will see it's properties, which contain the attributes of a web control. Another way is to click on the control and the right click and select properties.

By the way the OnTextChanged is an event, which you can associate it with a method, when this event happens.

```
OnTextChange="TextBoxText_Changed"
```

The TextBoxText_Changed would be a server side method, which will reside in your code behind class. In this method you will declare, what you want to happen, when this event is triggered,

Answer (score 0):

![Properties][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUUqZ.png
go to property window click on event icon and you can see all events associated to text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can look it up on the MSDN documentation page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox(v=vs.110).aspx